# Changing the digits of a jQuery Countdown

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am using the Countdown from this site: http://www.html.it/wp-content/uploads/script/demo/a/51105/demo.html

It is a jQuery Plug-In.

How can I change the font of the digits?

Comment: such a basic issue and OP has not shown any efforts to resolve it.

Comment: Please share some code for reference,

Comment: See: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can try something like this: `$(".ClassyCountdown-value").css("font-family", "Verdana");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the CSS property for the following selector:

```
div.ClassyCountdown-days span div
```

example:

```
div.ClassyCountdown-days span div {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Helvetica; /* example */
}
```

or simply:

```
span.ClassyCountdown-value div {
    font-size: 58px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```